# Interface methods and returning smart pointer to this (enable_shared_from_this)

Tags: c++, interface, shared-ptr, smart-pointers

I have a class (`Geometry`) that implements an interface (`LinkList`).  The code at the bottom of my example is obviously wrong, so I'm looking at implementing `std::enable_shared_from_this`.  Can `Geometry` safely inherit from `std::enable_shared_from_this<LinkList>` and can I safely change the `getLinkList()` method to `shared_from_this()`?  What happens if my `Geometry` class has multiple interfaces that it inherits, can I do this for all of the interfaces?

```
class Link
{
public:
    std::string getName() { return "the name"; }
};
class LinkList
{
public:
    virtual Link* getLink(int id) = 0;
    virtual int size() = 0;
};
class Geometry : LinkList
{
private:
    int state;
public:
    void doSomething() { state = 1; }
    virtual Link* getLink(int id) { return new Link(); }
    virtual int size() { return 1; }
    std::shared_ptr<LinkList> getLinkList() { return std::shared_ptr<LinkList>(this); }
};

void printList(std::shared_ptr<LinkList> linkList)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < linkList->size(); i++)
    {
        std::cout << linkList->getLink(i)->getName() << std::endl;
    }
}

void main()
{
    Geometry* geom = new Geometry();
    printList(geom->getLinkList());
    geom->doSomething(); // Error here
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The code at the bottom of my example is obviously wrong

The code there is not obviously wrong, the bug is in `getLinkedList` which gives ownership of `this` to a `shared_ptr` causing it to be deleted when the `printList` returns and the last shared_ptr object goes out of scope. So the last line of the example is rather non-obviously wrong, because the previous line subtly deleted the object.

> Can `Geometry` safely inherit from `std::enable_shared_from_this<LinkList>`

Yes, it's just a base class. It's nearly always safe to inherit from it (that doesn't mean you can use it safely though!)

> and can I safely change the `getLinkList()` method to `shared_from_this()`?

Only if the `Geometry` object is owned by a `shared_ptr`, and in your code it isn't:

```
Geometry* geom = new Geometry();
```

You need to store the pointer in a `shared_ptr` (preferably **immediately** when you create it) for the `enable_shared_from_this` base class to be usable, so this should be OK:

```
auto geom = std::make_shared<Geometry>();
printList(geom->shared_from_this());
geom->doSomething();
```

(Of course using `shared_from_this()` is pretty pointless there, because you already have the sahred_ptr anyway and could just do `printList(geom)`).

> What happens if my `Geometry` class has multiple interfaces that it inherits, can I do this for all of the interfaces?

No, if the class has multiple `enable_shared_from_this` base classes then the `shared_ptr` constructors won't know which one to initialize. I think you'll get an error due to ambiguity, or if not the `enable_shared_from_this` base classes will all hold an empty `weak_ptr` making them useless.

**Update**:

You could make `Geometry` derive from `enable_shared_from_this<Geometry>` (not from `enable_shared_from_this<LinkList>` and not from every interface), and define:

```
shared_ptr<LinkList> Geometry::getLinkList()
{
  return shared_from_this();
}
```

The object returned by `shared_from_this()` will convert implicitly to `shared_ptr<LinkList>`. You still need `this` to be owned by a `shared_ptr` in the first place though.

Comment: I was planning on using smart pointers; now it looks like I will need to have my interface methods return raw pointers.  Are there other better ways of handling this?  How about weak_ptr?

Comment: How about `weak_ptr` for what? I'm not sure what problem you're trying to solve - smart pointers are for managing ownership, you seem to want to use them for ... something else, I don't know what. Access to base classes? That's not related to ownership and lifetime management. Anyway, `weak_ptr` doesn't give you any advantage over `enable_shared_from_this` really, just means you have more work to do by hand.

Comment: You could use `enable_shared_from_this<Base>` where `Base` is a virtual base class shared by every interface in the hierarchy, then the `getLinkList()` function could do `return dynamic_pointer_cast<LinkList>(shared_from_this());` to convert from the `shared_ptr<Base>` to `shared_ptr<LinkList>`

Comment: My objective is to give component X access to a subset of a `Geometry` object by having the `Geometry` object implement the `LinkList` (or whatever) interface.  I don't want X to have a full `Geometry` object.  But I also don't want X to store a copy of the `LinkList` pointer.

Comment: _But I also don't want X to store a copy of the `LinkList` pointer._ I'm still not clear how `shared_ptr` helps - but I've added a new paragraph to the end of the answer that might do what you want